# JSON Schema how to reference an item created in a previous instance?

Tags: jsonschema

Lets say I want to have a json schema where first I define the "cars" that are part of a fleet. So I can create multiple cars with car make, color and plate.
Then, in the same schema, I want to assign those cars to different trips. So, define trips. ON each trip I define, I want to be able to "select" one of the cars previously defined.
How can I do that?

As an example, here a Schema, where I would want that in the "Trips" section, the "Car" is an "enum" of the cars defined above.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Fleet",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Cars": {
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "ID": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 50
          },
          "make": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "BMW",
              "FORD",
              "CHEVROLET"
              ]
          },
          "color": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 50
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Trips": {
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "Car": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 99
          },
          "Destination": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Couldn't find any solution googling around.